# How do I close the space at the final word so I can insert a period next to it?

Tags: javascript

It has to do with the iteration length right? How do I iterate it all but the last index?

```js
function createSentence(words) {
 var sentence = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    sentence += words[i] + ' ';
    if (i === words.length - 1)
        return sentence += '.';
    }
  }

var result1 = createSentence(['I', 'am', 'worth', 'it']);
console.log('should log "I am worth it.":', result1);

var result2 = createSentence(['My', 'problems', 'matter']);
console.log('should log "My problems matter.":', result2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CertainPerformance's solution is ideal.

If you want to avoid using `join` for educational purposes you could only append a space when i is not at the last position:

```js
function createSentence(words) {
 var sentence = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    sentence += words[i];
    if (i === words.length - 1) {
        return sentence += '.';
    } else {
        sentence += ' ';  // <---
    }
  }
}

var result1 = createSentence(['I', 'am', 'worth', 'it']);
console.log('should log "I am worth it.":', result1);

var result2 = createSentence(['My', 'problems', 'matter']);
console.log('should log "My problems matter.":', result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better idea: join by a space, then concatenate a single `.` onto the end afterwards:

```js
const createSentence = arr => arr.join(' ') + '.';

var result1 = createSentence(['I', 'am', 'worth', 'it']);
console.log('should log "I am worth it.":', result1);

var result2 = createSentence(['My', 'problems', 'matter']);
console.log('should log "My problems matter.":', result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

No looping is necessary. Just [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) all the array elements with a space and add a `.` to the end.

```js
function createSentence(words) {
 return words.join(" ") + ".";
}

console.log('should log "I am worth it.":', createSentence(['I', 'am', 'worth', 'it']));
console.log('should log "My problems matter.":', createSentence(['My', 'problems', 'matter']));
```